# How to disable or block TextView to not narrowed other elements of the Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have problem with my TextView, when something is written in it. It narrows the right layout.

like here:

1 Without something is written: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zItJw.jpg

2.Without something is written in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Nb4.jpg

My Layout Code:

1st bar:

```
<LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/czas_punkty_bez_napisu"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/dzialanie"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:textSize="25sp"
                                android:text="X razy Y" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/equal"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center"
                                android:textSize="25sp"
                                android:text="=" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tylemabyc"
                                android:textSize="25sp"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>
```

2nd bar

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/czas_punkty_bez_napisu"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/czas"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                         />

                </LinearLayout>
```

3rd bar:

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/czas_punkty_bez_napisu"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/wynik"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>
```

How to block 1st TextView to not narrows others ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use layout_weight property to tell android how much space each textView takes on the screen.   If you want all of them to have the same space you can add the layout_weight of 1 for all of them. 
You will also need to readjust your layout_width too. You will have to trade off for the layout_heght.   For example if i want 4 textviews in a horizontal line holding equal space "Horizontally" i would do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="This is verrry long text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="maybe not" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="let us see" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="ok" />
```

Comment: What if they are in different layouts ?